# How to combine two tables into one using my sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

i'm new in Database, i want to get a result from both sql table.
Here is the example

1. Table 1

| Item Code | Price |
| --- | --- |
| A001 | 5 Dollar |
| A002 | 6 Dollar |

2. Table 2 - Item Code Information

| Item Code | Item Description |
| --- | --- |
| A001 | Fish |
| A002 | Chicken |

And my question i want to get result with table 1 combine with 2 with item code, item description and price

| Item Code | Item Description | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A001 | Fish | 5 Dollar |
| A002 | Chicken | 6 Dollar |

Does anyone know how to do the SQL statement? Please help Thank you

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Comment: @P.Salmon There's nothing in this question about getting the most recent record from one of the tables.

Comment: Please share more details, like the condition you want to "combine" the results and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: You want a JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Use this codes:

```
SELECT T1.ItemCode,ItemDescription, Price
FROM TABLE1 T1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode
```

Comment: hi, what is T1?

Comment: T1 is alias of TABLE1

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.ItemCode, T2.ItemDescription, T1.Price
FROM TABLE1 T1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode;
```

Here T1 is an alias for Table 1 and T2 is alias for Table2.

Answer (score 0):

**Join both tables with item codes and select all the desired fields from both tables**

```
SELECT table2.itemcode,table2.itemdescription,table1.price FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.itemcode=table2.itemcode
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a Join. In this case you can use a star to Retrieve ALL items of both tables:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.item code = t2.item code.
```

The "item_code" is primary Key in t1 and a foreign Key in t2.

On this YouTube video you can learn about table joins:
https://youtu.be/0OQJDd3QqQM

Comment: Please do not just dump external links. Also, `tá Join` is not valid SQL syntax

Comment: Thank you for feedback, I corrected the typo and add context to the link

Answer (score 0):

Use join if you want to combine 2 or more table with sql.

```
SELECT Table1.itemcode, Table1.price, Table2.itemdescription FROM Table1 JOIN Tabel2 on Tabel1.itemcode = Tabel2.itemcode;
```

where

```
SELECT table_name.field_name, ... FROM table_name JOIN second_table_name on table_name.primary_key = second_table_name.foreign_key;
```

if you want to combine 3 then just add another join

```
SELECT table_name.field_name, ... FROM table_name JOIN second_table_name on table_name.primary_key = second_table_name.foreign_key JOIN third_table_name on table_name.primary_key = third_table_name.foreign_key;
```